# Single comments causing errors in PHP

Tags: php, syntax-error, comments

I am very embarrassed right now. I thought all the comments were working the same way.
But I found out that // and # are different from multi-annotation like /* */

```
/*$conText = preg_replace_callback('@(<a .*?href\s*=\s*(([\'"])(.*?)\3|([^\s>]+)).*?>(.*?)</a>)@si', create_function('$matches', 'return addLink($matches, 1);'), $conText);
$conText = preg_replace_callback('@(<area .*?href\s*=\s*(([\'"])(.*?)\3|([^\s>]+)).*?>)@si', create_function('$matches', 'return addLink($matches, 0);'), $conText);*/

//$conText = preg_replace_callback('@(<a .*?href\s*=\s*(([\'"])(.*?)\3|([^\s>]+)).*?>(.*?)</a>)@si', create_function('$matches', 'return addLink($matches, 1);'), $conText);

$conText = preg_replace_callback('@(<a .*?href\s*=\s*(([\'"])(.*?)\3|([^\s>]+)).*?>(.*?)</a>)@si', 'fnConText1', $conText);
$conText = preg_replace_callback('@(<area .*?href\s*=\s*(([\'"])(.*?)\3|([^\s>]+)).*?>)@si', 'fnConText0', $conText);
```

If there is an // code, there will be a syntax error, but if you delete the line, there will be no error.
Do you happen to know why this error occurs?

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: I am not sure how you can have an error here. Check you editor is not placing hidden characters in the code

Answer (score 2):

This is actually rather subtle, but can be seen more clearly with a simpler example:

```php
<?php 
echo 'hello'; 
// This is a comment with '?>' in
?>
```

Which results in this:

```
hello' in
?>
```

At a glance, it looks like the first `?>` is part of the comment, and the `<?php` block will continue until the second one (and at the time I write this, the site's syntax highlighter assumes so); but PHP doesn't parse it that way.

To see why, consider this example:

```php
<?php echo 'hello'; // this is a comment ?>
```

This is a self-contained piece of PHP which you could embed in a template file, with a comment contained inside the `<?php ... ?>` block. If the comment suppressed the meaning of `?>`, this wouldn't work.

So rather than "comment until the end of the line", `//` is defined as "comment until the end of the line *or the end of the current PHP block*, whichever comes first".

In contrast, a block comment is defined as ending at its own `*/` marker, so the following *does* comment out the first `?>`:

```php
<?php
echo 'hello';
/* This is a comment with '?>' in */
?>
```

Output:

```
hello
```

In your case, you effectively have this (with some other code before and after):

```php
<?php
//$conText = preg_replace_callback('@(<a .*?href\s*=\s*(([\'"])(.*?)\3|([^\s>]+)).*?>(.*?)</a>)@si', create_function('$matches', 'return addLink($matches, 1);'), $conText);
?>
```

Buried in the commented out line happens to be the characters `?>`. The parser doesn't look at the rest of the syntax, because it's a comment, but does pick up those characters as ending the PHP block.

The result is that PHP interprets it essentially as this:

```php
<?php
//$conText = preg_replace_callback('@(<a .*?href\s*=\s*(([\'"])(.*?)\3|([^\s>]+)).*
?>
(.*?)</a>)@si', create_function('$matches', 'return addLink($matches, 1);'), $conText);
?>
```

That leaves the end of the line which you were trying to comment out, and everything after it, as text to be output rather than code.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. But it's not related to the code that opens and closes php.

Comment: @EunAGo Look at the last few paragraphs again, starting "in your case"; I took the exact code you posted and explained why commenting it out with `//` doesn't work. It's not *intentionally* closing the PHP tag, but parsers don't read intentions, they read characters; I've edited to state that a bit more explicitly.